# MMPDS Coordinate System Adoption

Tags: metals, history

## How was the L, LT, ST coordinate system developed and adopted?

I am talking with some colleagues about comparing metallic and non-metallic materials. Obviously, "apples-to-apples" comparisons need to happen and that naturally means you need to equate certain directions in different coordinate systems.

This got me thinking: *"how did MMPDS settle on L, LT, ST?"* Was there resistance to forgings and extrusions being subjected to the same coordinate system (especially when you are looking at cylindrical vs non-cylindrical forms)? How were arguments against placing these various forms together in a single coordinate system resolved? Is there any documentation about the process that I could access, such as meeting notes?